# G is not simple.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order $p\cdot (p+1)$ , where $p$ is an odd prime.

> How can I show , that $G$ is not simple ?

I am stuck here.I tried with all the tools I have but I failed . I also tried sylow but could not get a way.please anyone help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing groups of order $p^{k}(p+1)$ are not simple, p prime](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24855/showing-groups-of-order-pkp1-are-not-simple-p-prime)

Comment: Yeah , but can it be done in a more simpler way.actually I did not get that.

Comment: Actually , I will be highly grateful if anyone writes the complete answer for me.I am facing problems from underatanding those comments.

Comment: The detailed answer to the linked question has an argument for $k>1$, saying that the case $k=1$ needs a different one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $G$ simple.

**Hint 1**

> The number of $p$-Sylow subgroups is $p+1$, so that if $P$ is one of these subgroups, we have $N_{G}(P) = P = C_{G}(P)$.

**Hint 2**

> There are $(p-1)(p+1) = p^{2} -1$ elements of order $p$.

**Hint 3**

> There are $p+1$ elements left. Let $\Omega$ be the set of the non-identity elements among them, so $\Omega$ has $p$ elements.

**Hint 4**

> $P$ acts by conjugation on $\Omega$. Since $C_{G}(P) = P$, $P$ acts transitively on $\Omega$ by conjugation.

**Hint 5**

> All the elements of $\Omega$ have the same order, so $p+1$ is prime.

**Hint 6**

> $p$ is odd.

Comment: What is N G (P) and C G (P)?

Comment: Please expain 2nd part of the 1st hint.

Comment: @mathislove, [Normalizer and centralizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer).

Comment: I will be also grateful if you kindly explain hint 4

Comment: @mathislove, you need a basic understanding of [Sylow theorem's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems) to go through this kind of solution.

Comment: The points of  normaliser is in P but how are they exactly equal ? Same for cebtralizer